# How to Record All Logins In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to store all successfull login to SQL Server via SQL authentication Or Windows.

Please  Help me.

Answer (score 2):

In SSMS, right click on the database and select properties. Security tab. Change Login Auditing to "Successful logins only"

For a multi-instanced machine, that results in the following query being executed

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'AuditLevel', REG_DWORD, 1
GO
```

As you can see, it modifies registry values to make this change happen. As with other registry level changes, it does not take affect until the service has been restarted.

Audit levels

- 0 None
- 1 Successful logins only
- 2 failed logins only
- 3 Successful and failed logins

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark here but I would probably read up on how SQL Server already does that for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188470.aspx

Comment: Thanks all.....    I think this article is very useful  [link](http://sqlnetcode.blogspot.com/2011/11/record-all-logins-logon-trigger-in-sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all...
I googled many sites and also found the same thing...
I want to share it here so it can be useful for you..
http://sqlnetcode.blogspot.com/2011/11/record-all-logins-logon-trigger-in-sql.html